# How to dissolve and homogenize DNA

Tags: organic-chemistry, dna-rna

I have about 20-30 grams of purified mammalian DNA preserved in EDTA. It is clumped up and solid. I need to dissolve and homogenize it, so it can be aliquoted, without damaging or lysing or fragmenting the DNA. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I think you can do this with TE buffer or water, the latter of which needs to be 18 M$\Omega$ RO.

Comment: How large are the DNA pieces (eg number of base pairs)? That’s a big factor in how susceptible they are to mechanical damage. If it’s a small plasmid, you can pipette vigorously without much worry, but if it’s genomic DNA you need to be much gentler

Comment: @Andrew I updated the questions. It's mammalian genomic DNA.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you'll get a much better answer if you migrate this question to biology SE, but here's what I've done:

1. add your chosen volume of nuclease-free TE buffer or water (assuming the DNA is precipitated with salts).
2. Leave it in the fridge (~4 C) overnight to allow for slow hydration.
3. Gently resuspend the DNA by very slowly pipetting the solution up and down using a 1 mL pipette with about 1 cm of the tip cut off so that the opening is substantially larger than normal.
4. Make aliquots for future use so as to minimize handling.